# Change from name in postfix

Tags: postfix, email-server

I'm not able to change from name when i send out a message with postfix. I always get root@localhost.localdomain, i've already cheked whole process, but something is missing, could you take a look?

in /etc/postfix/main.cf i have

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

append_dot_mydomain = no

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mydomain.com
mydomain = mydomain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
#myorigin = $mydomain
#mydestination = mydomain.com, localhost.localdomain, localhost.localdomain, localhost
mydestination = $myhostname localhost.$mydomain localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
```

**postconf -n**

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
mydestination = $myhostname localhost.$mydomain localhost
mydomain = mydomain.com
myhostname = mydomain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_destination_concurrency_limit = 2
smtp_destination_rate_delay = 3s
smtp_extra_recipient_limit = 2
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

**cat  /etc/mailname**

```
mydomain.com
```

i send a test email with:

```
mail -s "test" my@gmail.com < test.txt
```

into **/var/log/mail.log** i get:

```
ED8021574F: from=<root@localhost.localdomain>, size=35175, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

and in my inbox i get this in source email:

```
From: root@localhost.localdomain (root)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
mail -s "test" my@gmail.com < test.txt
```

to

```
mail -s "test" my@gmail.com -a "From:user@domain.tld" < test.txt
```

If that domain has an SPF record that does not include the system you're sending from or it's smarthost (if using one), the mail will likely be treated as spam.